# Latex references are roman numerals in text and arabic numerals in description

Tags: latex

I have a number of figures referenced in my document. The figure references appear as roman numerals in the text. However figure descriptions are in arabic numerals. The numbers are also off - in this example the figure name is "Fig 4" and the reference reads "Figure VII". The document header, figure reference, and figure description are below (I included all packages in case there are funny interactions that I'm unaware of). Any idea what's going on?

Document header:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{alphanum}
\usepackage[bf, labelsep = period, font = doublespacing, figurename=Fig.]{caption}
\captionsetup{position=top}
\usepackage{alnumsec}
\alnumsecstyle{R L a}
\usepackage[default]{harvard}
\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}
```

Figure Reference:

```
    \ref{Fig: histogram1}
```

Figure Description:

```
    \begin{figure}\caption{<stuff>}
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics{histogram1.pdf}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}\label{Fig: histogram1}
```

Comment: You are multiple mistakes in your code. Specifically, `\label` should be *inside* the `figure` environment *after* `\caption` (see [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/5764)); also, use `\centering`, not the `center` environment (see [When should we use `\begin{center}` instead of `\centering`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/5764)).

Answer (score 5):

What @Werner said worked for me. For example, we can change this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\label{fig:topo1-ofq}
\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{img/ofquality_topology_1_liso.png}}
\caption{First test Topology}
\end{figure}
```

By this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{img/ofquality_topology_1_liso.png}}
\caption{First test Topology}
\label{fig:topo1-ofq}
\end{figure}
```

And it will works without making huge changes.